# Is it possible to know there exists a shorter decision tree

Tags: machine-learning, cart, entropy, decision-theory

Let us consider that we have a decision tree based upon information gain. This can not always be a optimal tree with regards to tree complexity. How do we approach this kind of situation?

Is there some example which shows relatively small decision tree exists that classifies instances correctly and if we apply greedy algorithm(with information gain) then we end up with larger tree?

Feel free to change the tags. I could not find right tags related to question.

Comment: Figuring out whether or not a decision tree is optimal sounds like an NP hard problem. However, there should definitely be an optimum tree (assuming the data is not truly continuous), since there would only be finitely many trees of each depth.

Comment: @AlexR. Yes, the problem is certainly NP-hard. However, for certain special cases it is feasible to either _compute_ the best solution (e.g., when all variables are binary, known as "logic regression trees") or to _approximate_ it (e.g., by evolutionary algorithms). Our `evtree` package for R implements such an evolutionary learning method for regression and classification trees, see: http://dx.doi.org/10.18637/jss.v061.i01